# Can't change to home directory

Tags: linux, home-directory

When logging into my virtual server as a non-root user, I suddenly get the following error:

> "Could not chdir to home directory
>   /var/www/vhosts/prosodylab.org/web_users/username: Permission denied
>   -bash: /var/www/vhosts/prosodylab.org/web_users/username/.bash_profile:
>   Permission denied"

I checked the permissions in the user directory (they're set to 700, and I also changed to 777 to check, with now effect).

This affects all users (including if I create a new user), but as root user I can still change into the relevant directories without problem.

`echo $HOME` returns the right directory.

Here is the directory entry of the home directory of the user (when set to 700):

```
drwx------ 20 username    psaserv 4096 Jun  5 16:56 username
```

`grep username /etc/passwd` returns the following output, so the directory seems to be set correctly:

```
username:x: [...] ::/var/www/vhosts/prosodylab.org/web_users/username:/bin/bash
```

The server is a 1&1 dedicated virtual linux server, and it's worked fine for many years. I might have inadvertently changed something, but if so the I don't know what.

Does anyone know what might be the problem?

Comment: This site is for programming questions. We are not general tech support.

Comment: Probably better asked at superuser or serverfault.

Comment: Thanks, I will repost on serverfault.

Answer (score 1):

Gain more access login as root and check the permissions on the parent folder

Comment: actually, this solved it--one of the parent folders didn't have execute permission set for non-group, non-users.